# Verificar se o dia x cai em um Sabado ou Domingo

Tags: java, data

Estou fazendo um sistema que será uma Agenda, nesse sistema tem uma opção de repetir o compromisso salvo quinzenalmente, ou seja eu salvo o compromisso e o sistema irá me notificar a cada 15 dias. Porém esse compromisso não pode cair no `sábado` ou `domingo`. Como posso fazer essa verificação?

Por exemplo como é quinzenal se eu adicionar um compromisso hoje ele irá salvar o dia de hoje e incrementar mais 15 dias, se o resultado cair em um sábado ou domingo ele pula e salva o compromisso na segunda feira. Ou seja, pra verificar se o dia da semana é sábado ou domingo tenho que passar uma `data(data futura)` como parâmetro e em cima dessa data fazer a verificação

Comment: já trabalhou com calendar? ele possui DAY_OF_MONTH você poderia subtrarir do seus dia atual ou fazer por semana  DAY_OF_WEEK -2 que seria o dia 6 e 7 da semana.

Comment: Está usando o Java 8? Se sim, existe a classe LocalDate que tem um método chamado getDayOfWeek, através dele você pode validar qual é o dia da semana. Caso esteja trabalhando com Java 7 pode usar a dica do @WellingtonAvelino.

Comment: Beleza, vou tentar usar as duas e ver qual se encaixa melhor. Mas é possível com essas classes descobrir qual é o dia da semana do mês que vem por exemplo?

Comment: editei a pergunta para explicar um pouco melhor o que eu estou tentando fazer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dá pra usar `Calendar` mesmo.

**Demo** (obviamente, metade do código pode ser removido pois é de `System.out.println`...e também utilizar `SWITCH`, enfim...é só para efeito de demonstração)

**`Main.java`**

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Calendar data = Calendar.getInstance();
            //data.set(2015, Calendar.JULY, 5); // ou neste neste formato ao invés de usar o simpleFormat abaixo
            SimpleDateFormat simpleFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

            data.setTime(simpleFormat.parse("06/07/2015"));

            System.out.println("Data antes: " + simpleFormat.format(data.getTime()));
            data = checaFDS(data);
            System.out.println("Data apos: " + simpleFormat.format(data.getTime()));
        }
        catch (ParseException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Verifica se data á sábado ou domingo e acrescenta dias conforme necessário p/ retornar dia de semana.
     *
     * @param   data        Um objeto Calendar
     * @return  Calendar
     */
    public static Calendar checaFDS(Calendar data)
    {
        // se for domingo
        if (data.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SUNDAY)
        {
            data.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
            System.out.println("Eh domingo, mudando data para +1 dias");
        }
        // se for sábado
        else if (data.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SATURDAY)
        {
            data.add(Calendar.DATE, 2);
            System.out.println("Eh sabado, mudando data para +2 dias");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Eh dia de semana, mantem data");
        }
        return data;
    }

}
```

**Sábado (04/07/2015)**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Domingo (05/07/2015)**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Dia de semana (06/07/2015)**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: haha, minha ideia era exatamente essa, mas to sem tempo de colocar exemplos :(

Comment: Muito obrigado, implementei sua ideia em meu sistema e funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: Imagina Techies ! (Pois é @WellingtonAvelino kkkk)

Answer (score 3):

O segredo é utilizar o `u` no padrão do [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), como no código:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class ProximoDiaDaSemana {

    private static DateFormat DIA_DA_SEMANA = new SimpleDateFormat("u");

    private static long MILISEGUNDOS_EM_UM_DIA = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

    private static int DOMINGO = 7;

    private static int SABADO = 6;

    private static int diferencaSabadoOuDomingo(int diaDaSemana) {
        if (diaDaSemana == DOMINGO) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (diaDaSemana == SABADO) {
            return 2;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    private static Date obterDataProximoCompromisso(Date dataInicial, int dias) {
        Date daquiXDias = new Date(dataInicial.getTime() + dias * MILISEGUNDOS_EM_UM_DIA);
        int diferencaSabadoOuDomingo = diferencaSabadoOuDomingo(Integer.valueOf(DIA_DA_SEMANA.format(daquiXDias)));
        if (diferencaSabadoOuDomingo > 0) {
            return new Date(daquiXDias.getTime() + diferencaSabadoOuDomingo * MILISEGUNDOS_EM_UM_DIA);
        } else {
            return daquiXDias;
        }
    }
}
```

Assim, ao executarmos um teste:

```
    private static DateFormat EXIBICAO = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.FULL, Locale.getDefault());

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Locale.setDefault(new Locale("pt-BR"));
        Date hoje = new Date();
        System.out.println("Hoje: " + EXIBICAO.format(hoje));
        for (int i = 1; i <= 15; i++) {
            System.out.println("Se agendar para daqui " + i + " dias cairá em: "
                    + EXIBICAO.format(ProximoDiaDaSemana.obterDataProximoCompromisso(new Date(), i)));
        }
    }
```

Temos o resultado desejado:

> Hoje: Sexta-feira, 10 de Julho de 2015
>
> Se agendar para daqui 1 dias cairá em: Segunda-feira, 13 de Julho de
>   2015
>
> Se agendar para daqui 2 dias cairá em: Segunda-feira, 13 de Julho de
>   2015
>
> Se agendar para daqui 3 dias cairá em: Segunda-feira, 13 de Julho de
>   2015
>
> Se agendar para daqui 4 dias cairá em: Terça-feira, 14 de Julho de
>   2015
>
> Se agendar para daqui 5 dias cairá em: Quarta-feira, 15 de Julho de
>   2015
>
> Se agendar para daqui 6 dias cairá em: Quinta-feira, 16 de Julho de
>   2015
>
> Se agendar para daqui 7 dias cairá em: Sexta-feira, 17 de Julho de
>   2015
>
> Se agendar para daqui 8 dias cairá em: Segunda-feira, 20 de Julho de
>   2015
>
> Se agendar para daqui 9 dias cairá em: Segunda-feira, 20 de Julho de
>   2015
>
> Se agendar para daqui 10 dias cairá em: Segunda-feira, 20 de Julho de
>   2015
>
> Se agendar para daqui 11 dias cairá em: Terça-feira, 21 de Julho de
>   2015
>
> Se agendar para daqui 12 dias cairá em: Quarta-feira, 22 de Julho de
>   2015
>
> Se agendar para daqui 13 dias cairá em: Quinta-feira, 23 de Julho de
>   2015
>
> Se agendar para daqui 14 dias cairá em: Sexta-feira, 24 de Julho de
>   2015
>
> Se agendar para daqui 15 dias cairá em: Segunda-feira, 27 de Julho de
>   2015

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta